# Is it possible to toggle app visibility via an app or automation?

Tags: automator, window-manager

I'm trying to figure out a way to toggle the visibility of any app, regardless of the active desktop space, similar to how the app [Slidepad](https://setapp.com/apps/slidepad) works, if possible. Slidepad is limited to being a browser, so if you wanted to use Slack, you'd need to use the browser-app.

But I'd like to be able to toggle in Finder, Slack, etc. Having a slide-in animation from the right-hand side would be great if it's possible.

Is this possible via scripts, a window management app, or any other way?

Thanks

Comment: Well, I use command+tab to toggle the visibility of any app. What exactly are you trying to accomplish? Do you want the foremost window to assume a fixed size and position at the right of the screen? And when it loses focus to go all the way to the right and stay "hidden"?

Comment: @MateusRibeiro yes that’s correct. For example if I’m using Slack, a Finder window, or whatever else. Each app would have a hot key that brings it into view in the same window position and size. Ideally that would happen regardless of how many displays you’re using and would always appear in the active display.

Comment: I see. Well to make things easier, I would suggest a simple script to change size and position of the frontmost window from whatever app is selected. This way you will only use one shortcut. Or else you can have one service for every app, but this will require a lot of copy/paste, editing and setup on your end.

Comment: Thanks, I was able to create a basic script like you suggested, although I can't access a specific window space on a multi-monitor setup with Apple Scripts.

Comment: that is out of my league, I have only one monitor, but I am pretty sure the wizards around here can help you. This sounds like a feasible feature, addressing one of the screens. This way you can have one shortcut for every monitor and quickly push your windows around.